# Maximum call stack size exceed with MongoDB and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, aggregate

I'm using NodeJS with MongoClient (mongodb). I'm trying to fetch some data from the MongoDB database by calling the function aggregate on my collection. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded


    at Object.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:41)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\charts_generator\node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:58:59)
```

Here is my code:

```
const col = client.db(dbName).collection("statistiquesQuotidiennes");
col.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: { spectacle: artist }},
        {
            $group: {
            _id: { month: { $month: "$jourVente" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$jourVente" }, year: { $year: "$jourVente" } },
            totalTickets: {$sum:"$billets"}
            }
        }
    ],
    function(err,docs)
    {
        if (err)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            socket.emit("changerArtiste",docs);
        }

    }
)
```

Comment: what is the total number of records you are fetching